# ERROR POST net::ERR_FAILED AL HACER PETICIÓN POST DE FRONTED A BACKEND

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, api

Hola buen día desarrolle una pequeña api en php la he probado con postman y funciona bien. Pero al hacer una petición POST desde un frontend con vuejs me sale error; con GET no tengo problemas me trae los datos, es la primera vez que realizo este tipo de ejercicios y no tengo mucho conocimiento, busque en internet y el problema podría deberse a CORS es por eso que agregue esas cabeceras en el backend pero aún así presento esta falla. El error que tengo es el sgte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el fronted tengo el sgte código:

```
async addTask() {
        const datos = new FormData();
        datos.append('task', this.task);
        const taskToSend = Object.fromEntries(datos);
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost/backendToDoList/tareas', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(taskToSend)
        });
        console.log(response);
    }
```

En el backend hice un switch case de esta manera:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch ($method) {
  case 'GET':
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $tarea = new Tareas();
        $tarea->setCodigo(intval($_GET['url']));
        $taskList = new TareasImpl();
        $tasks = $taskList->buscarTarea($tarea);
        echo json_encode($tasks);
    } else {
        $taskList = new TareasImpl();
        $tasks = $taskList->listarTareas();
        echo json_encode($tasks);
    }
    break;
case 'POST':
    $task = new Tareas();
    $cuerpo = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $datos = json_decode($cuerpo, true);
    $task->setTarea($datos['tarea']);
    $taskList = new TareasImpl();
    $tasks = $taskList->registrarTarea($task);
    if ($tasks) {
         echo json_encode('exito');
     } else {
         echo json_encode('no exito');
     }
    break;
case 'PUT':
    $task = new Tareas();
    $taskList = new TareasImpl();
    $cuerpo = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $datos = json_decode($cuerpo, true);
    $task->setTarea($datos['tarea']);
    $task->setEstado(boolval($datos['estado']));
    $task->setCodigo(intval($_GET['url']));
    $tasks = $taskList->modificarTareas($task);
    if($tasks){
        echo json_encode('exito');
    }else{
        echo json_encode('no exito');
    }
    break;
case 'DELETE':
    $cuerpo = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $dato = json_decode($cuerpo, true);
    $task = new Tareas();
    $taskList = new TareasImpl();
    $task->setCodigo($dato['codigo']);
    $tasks = $taskList->eliminarTareas($task);
    if($tasks){
        echo json_encode('exito');
    }else{
        echo json_encode('no exito');
    }
    break;
default:
    echo json_encode('NO ENTRASTEA NINGUNA PETICIÓN');
    break;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Buen día a todos llegue a solucionar mi problema espero que a alguien le pueda servir, indigando por internet al parecer me faltaba una cabecera más en el backend para que me acepte diversos Content-type como el "application/json". Añadí la sgte. cabecera a mi backend y con esto ya no me sale el error que presentaba :):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo. Pero en que parte del backend exactamente?, yo no encuentro ningún archivo de configuración para meter ese header. Nada, logre arreglarlo poniendo un @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000"); en el controller de mi aplicación. Se lo debes poner a cada una de las peticiones.